# CakePHP Find Condition does not appear in SQL Query

Tags: cakephp, find, conditional-statements, where-clause

My Find conditions don't seem to be making their way into the SQL based on Debugkits SQL log. Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong? This is my first time trying to filter my Find results.

BillingCenters controller

```
$conditions = array(
    'BillingCenter.isactive' => '1'
);
$this->set(
    'billingcenters', 
    $this->BillingCenter->find('all', array($conditions))
);
```

The resulting SQL Query shown by DebugKit is.. (missing the WHERE clause???)

```
SELECT 
    `BillingCenter`.`id`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`startdate`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`enddate`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`name`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`isactive`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`created`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`modified` 
FROM 
    `bm`.`billing_centers` AS `BillingCenter` 
WHERE 
    1 = 1
```

If i changed the controller code to

```
$this->set(
    'billingcenters', 
    $this->BillingCenter->find('all')
);
```

The resulting SQL is STILL the same.

```
SELECT 
    `BillingCenter`.`id`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`startdate`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`enddate`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`name`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`isactive`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`created`, 
    `BillingCenter`.`modified` 
FROM 
    `bm`.`billing_centers` AS `BillingCenter` 
WHERE 
    1 = 1
```

Comment: Just to make this clearer I disabled all associations between the Billing Center Model and any other models. So this is a pure single model Find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bites me all the time.

Change your find line to this:

```
$this->set(
    'billingcenters', 
    $this->BillingCenter->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions))
);
```

Comment: Omg this finally works. I always thought while Cakephp makes things so much easier in so many other ways, their Find method that helps u generate SQL is kind of convoluted. Thank you so much for your help Ben.

Comment: @aDvo perhaps the very first time you need to specify e.g. fields, order or limit, you'll change your mind ;).